# Hamcrest matcher to return items instead of iterable of items

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I am trying to validate test as:

```
assertThat("array_field", row.getArray("count_to_six_agg") ,
                   containsInAnyOrder(Arrays.asList(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L)));
```

For reference: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.html#assertThat(java.lang.String,%20T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)

Here containsInAnyOrder(Arrays.asList(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L)) returns

> iterable with items [<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]>] in any order

I want it to return

> items [<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]>] only.

How can that be done?

Answer (score -1):

You selected the following overload of [containsInAnyOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(T...))

```
public static <T> Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends T>> containsInAnyOrder(T... items)
```

and passed only one element - a list.

You need to pass each element as e separate argument:

```
containsInAnyOrder(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L)
```